# Trigger.IO - Rewriting files on prebuild - index.html missing

Tags: hook, trigger.io

I am using a node script to rewrite some files including the index.html in the prebuild section of a forge build in Trigger.IO.

I have tested the script directly and it works fine. Once I use it in the prebuild I get the following error:

```
Missing index.html in source directory, index.html is required by Forge.
```

Anyone got any tips on what I should be doing or why this might be erroring?

This is the script I'm using:

```
var fs = require('fs-sync')
  , fs2 = require('fs')
  , path = require('path');

replaceFiles = function(dirPath, sourcePath) {
  try { var files = fs2.readdirSync(dirPath); }
  catch(e) { return; }
  if (files.length > 0)
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var filePath = dirPath + '/' + files[i];
      var fileparts = files[i].split('.');
      if(!fs2.statSync(filePath).isFile() && files[i] == 'lib'){
        fs.delete(filePath);
        console.log('deleted lib directory');
      } else if (fs2.statSync(filePath).isFile() && (fileparts[1] == 'jpg' || fileparts[1] == 'png' || fileparts[1] == 'html')){
        fs.delete(filePath);
        console.log('deleted ' + filePath);         
      }
    }
    fs.copy(sourcePath, dirPath, {});
    console.log('copy done!');
};

var target = process.argv[2];
console.log(target);

replaceFiles('.', './' + target);
```

Trigger.IO runs the following command:

```
node hook.js android
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger apps require an index.html in the root of the src folder, if that file is not there when the app is run then you will see that error message.

It looks like your code deletes all html files before copying the files in `./android` to `./`, my guess is you have no index.html in the android folder, so no index.html exists in your built app.

You can see what files actually make it into your built app by looking in the `development/android/assets/src` folder in your app's folder.

Comment: Thank you the development folder was a really good hint. it happens that I added the ios and android folders i was copying to the .forgeignore so it wasn't there to copy from. I removed them from .forgeignore and then deleted them both at the end of the script - it now works!